# Data is reinserted in the table on using @ElementCollection on Set<String>

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I am using JPA 2.0 in my project and I have used @ElementCollection on one of my property in the Pojo class.

Following is my java entity class :

```
@Entity
@Embeddable
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_test")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_test", sequenceName = "seq_test")
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetClass = String.class)
@CollectionTable(name = "denied_set")
@OrderColumn
private Set<String> deniedSet;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetClass = String.class)
@CollectionTable(name = "masked_set")
@OrderColumn
private Set<String> maskedSet;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetClass = String.class)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_groups")
@OrderColumn
private Set<String> userGroups;

public Long getId() {
  return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
  this.id = id;
}

public Set<String> getDeniedSet() {
  return deniedSet;
}

public void setDeniedSet(Set<String> deniedSet) {
  this.deniedSet = deniedSet;
}

public Set<String> getMaskedSet() {
  return maskedSet;
}

public void setMaskedSet(Set<String> maskedSet) {
  this.maskedSet = maskedSet;
}

public Set<String> getUserGroups() {
  return userGroups;
}

public void setUserGroups(Set<String> userGroups) {
  this.userGroups = userGroups;
}

}
```

I am using Spring Data JPA Repositories for interaction with database. Data is properly inserted into the database table. When I delete some data from the table, I can see in the logs that the delete queries are executed on the child tables also and after that the same data is reinserted into the table.

Can anyone help me understand if I am missing anything in the code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just some questions that might help you:

1. Do you need @Embedded public class Test? If you are not using it in
   another owning entity then remove it.
2. Specify which column should be used as id for the
   @ElementCollection. Use something like this: 
   @CollectionTable(name="denied_set",
   JoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="COLUMN_NAME")) or use Embedded if the
   deniad_set is Embeddable.
3. Fetch type is lazy by default on ElementCollection and do you really need targetClass there?

Otherwise it looks correct to me...